# Getting unique id in view hierachy of getchildView(...) in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

How to get/identify unique id in view hierarchy. below is my code snippet fot getChildView(...)

```
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

if (convertView == null) 
    {
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_insurance, null);
    }

    company = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_CompanyName);
    interest = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_Interest);
    duration = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_Duration);
    btnSave = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    company.setTag(R.id.string_key1, childPosition);
    //interest.setTag(childPosition, childPosition);
    //duration.setTag(childPosition, childPosition);        
    btnSave.setTag(R.id.string_key2, childPosition);
    //btnDelete.setTag(childPosition, childPosition);

    company.setText(child.getCompanyName().toString());
    interest.setText(child.getInterest()+"");
    duration.setText(child.getDuration()+"");

    btnSave.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int viewtag = (Integer) v.getTag(R.id.string_key2);
            if (childPosition == viewtag){
                durationValue = (duration.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0.0f : Float.parseFloat(duration.getText().toString()));
                interestValue = (interest.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0.0f : Float.parseFloat(interest.getText().toString()));

                Log.v("durationValue", "durationValue ======" + durationValue +"========"+ interestValue);

                if (checkingForEmptyFields()){
                    int updatedRows = dbManager.updateInsurance(companyValue, durationValue, 15);
                    if (updatedRows > 0){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, InsurancePanelInflator.class));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Problem occured while updating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                 }
                else
                {
                     Toast.makeText(mContext, "Fill Mandatory Fields First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }   
            }


        }
    });
```

Now on click Save button in below image when i getText it always get the bottom row values as all views have same id. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: You are reusing the same id's in every entry, use the id of entry to retrieve the entry and then call findViewById on that entry to retrieve the current company, interest and duration. E.g. a listview contains items with the same id's for all the views inside, the items are differentiated by using the items id of the item itself and not the id's of the views inside.

Comment: thanks for ur comments. It doesnot work for me: expandableRow = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lnrExpListRow);
  
  company = (EditText) expandableRow.findViewById(R.id.et_CompanyName);
  interest = (EditText) expandableRow.findViewById(R.id.et_Interest);
  duration = (EditText) expandableRow.findViewById(R.id.et_Duration);
  btnSave = (Button) expandableRow.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
  btnDelete = (Button) expandableRow.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh you are keeping your `EditText`'s in class variables, never do that for `ListView` items. Doing this will change their reference every time `getView()` or `getChildView()` is called and you will end up with dandling reference. Do it like this and you are good to go:

```
final ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_insurance, null);
}

final EditText company = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_CompanyName);
final EditText interest = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_Interest);
final EditText duration = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_Duration);
final Button btnSave = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
final Button btnDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
// no need for tags
company.setText(child.getCompanyName().toString());
interest.setText(child.getInterest()+"");
duration.setText(child.getDuration()+"");

btnSave.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // no need to test position
            durationValue = (duration.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0.0f : Float.parseFloat(duration.getText().toString()));
            interestValue = (interest.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0.0f : Float.parseFloat(interest.getText().toString()));

            Log.v("durationValue", "durationValue ======" + durationValue +"========"+ interestValue);

            if (checkingForEmptyFields()){
                int updatedRows = dbManager.updateInsurance(companyValue, durationValue, 15);
                if (updatedRows > 0){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, InsurancePanelInflator.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Problem occured while updating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
            } else {
                 Toast.makeText(mContext, "Fill Mandatory Fields First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: How i will get updated values from EditText. Using your suggested solution I can re-save only existing old data. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Edited my answer... I got your problem this time, I guess.

Comment: Also please use efficient `ListView` design guidelines i.e. use ViewHolder pattern in `getChildView()` method.

Comment: thanks for ur effort, but this is not solution to my problem. My problem is when i click save it always pick last row values (from above pic). I want to pick corresponding rows values on corresponding save buttons. I know it is possible with setTag() and getTag(), but how please help me brother :)

Comment: How this is not a solution? If you are keeping `Edittext`'s reference in class members then it will get updated every time `getChildView()` is called. And in your case it is being called sequentially i.e. for your last row `getChildView()` is called in the end and you are left with last rows references. Have you tried my solution? At least try it once. :)

Comment: Thanks Your this comment worked for me: [Also please use efficient ListView design guidelines i.e. use ViewHolder pattern in getChildView() method.]. Use of ViewHolder worked.